# trying to install a wordpress multisite in a subfolder and have custom subsite urls

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I'm working on a project for a client where they currently have a WordPress blog installed on its own server and the url is www.example.com/blog. Now they want to convert the WordPress install to a multisite. The trick is they want the subsite urls to be www.example.com/community and www.example.com/forum. I was successful converting the single site to a multisite and imported all the content on localhost.

What do I have to do to get the subsite urls to work the way I want on the live server? I assume I need to add something to the htaccess file but I'm not sure if I need to do it in the website root folder or the WordPress root folder or both. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your current .htaccess file? Did you copy it from Network Admin > Settings > Network Setup? The .htaccess file is located in the root directory of your WordPress installation.

Comment: Yes I'm using the recommended htaccess file in my WordPress root folder for multisite installs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/184417)